# How to make a AJAX request to a Desktop version of a site via the Mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile

The mobile site I'm working on is completely different than its desktop version. I need to make an AJAX call via the mobile site that will bring in data from the desktop version. It seems that the AJAX call will make the GET request only on the calling version of the site.

This code only returns the mobile site data when called on the mobile site:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: window.location.href,
                success: function(data) {
                    var response = $(data);
                    //Returns mobile site data
                }
            });
```

Is there any way to force the GET request to use the desktop version?

Comment: Define "desktop version" and "mobile version". That isn't a standard feature of a website. You must have something that that looks at some variable and assumes mobile or desktop based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an AJAX request to *the current URL*:

```
url: window.location.href
```

This is highly unconventional.  But more to the point, the browser doesn't know or care what the difference is between "desktop" and "mobile".  It just makes requests and displays the responses.  If the current URL doesn't handle the AJAX request then you'll need to make the request to a URL that does:

```
url: 'someSpecificUrl'
```

To make this easier and consistent through the different versions of your application, I recommend *separating* your UI URLs from your API URLs.  Both versions of the UI can then make requests to the same API URLs.